EF Core 8, LinqKit - Expression in Include where clauses throws variable referenced from scope ', but it is not defined
When invoke the expression in EF Core .Include .Where clauses, I get an InvalidOperationException:

variable '___zip_0' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

DbContext configuration with LinqKit:
UseSqlServer("Server=TMATEBOOK2023\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Person;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;")
        .WithExpressionExpanding();

SpecificationBase class
public abstract class Specification<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ToExpression();
    
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity)
    {
        Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = ToExpression().Compile();
        return predicate(entity);
    }
       
    public Specification()
    {
    }

    public Specification(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>? criteria) 
        => Criteria = criteria;
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Criteria { get; set; }
    
    public List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> IncludeExpression { get; } = new();
    public List<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>>> NestedIncludes { get; }
                = new List<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>>>();
    public List<string> IncludeStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>? OrderByExpression { get; private set; }
    public Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>? OrderByDescendingExpression { get; private set; }
    
    protected void AddInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> includeExpression)=> IncludeExpression.Add(includeExpression);
    protected virtual void AddNestedInclude(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> nestedIncludeExpression)
    {
        NestedIncludes.Add(nestedIncludeExpression);
    }

    protected virtual void AddInclude(string includeString)
    {
        IncludeStrings.Add(includeString);
    }

    protected void AddOrderBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByExpression)
            => OrderByExpression = orderByExpression;
    
    protected void AddOrderByDescending(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByDescendingExpression)
           => OrderByDescendingExpression = orderByDescendingExpression;
    
    public Specification<TEntity> And(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<TEntity>(this, specification);
    }
       
    public Specification<TEntity> Or(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<TEntity>(this, specification);
    }
}

Specification in use
public class AddressByZipSpecification : Specification<Address>
{
    public int _zip { get; set; }

    public AddressByZipSpecification(int zip)
    {
        _zip = zip;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Address, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return address => address.Zip == _zip;
    }
}

How can I use the specification in the test?
 var zipExp = new AddressByZipSpecification(12).ToExpression();
 var result = await dbContext.Person.Include(p => p.AddressList.Where(a => zipExp.Invoke(a))).ToListAsync();

The dbContext.Address.Where(ZipExp).ToListAsync() works very well, I am confused what is happens with the declaration of variable in the zipExp expression.
If I replace the expression with it works well, too.
Expression<Func<Address, bool>> addressFilter = a => a.StreetNr > 199;


This line looks broken var result = await dbContext.Person.Include(p => p.AddressList.Where(a => zipExp.Invoke(a))).ToListAsync();. I would go with this: var result = await dbContext.Person.Include(p => p.AddressList).Where(a => zipExp.Invoke(a))).ToListAsync();. But what do you mean with How can I use the specification in the test?. What do you want to test and how your test looks like?
